# the edit dropdownList doesn't show the value of the model

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to edit an employee, but in the edit view the dropdownList doesn't show the selected item based on the model

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {   
        Employee employee = db.tblEmploye.Find(id);
        return View(employee);
    }
```

edit.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Gender, new List<SelectListItem>
               {
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Male", Value = "Male"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Female", Value = "Female"}
               }, "Select Gender", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you give us the type of the Gender property of your Model class.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set [Selected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlistitem.selected?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_SelectListItem_Selected) to true for the option you want to be selected.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Gender, new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{Text = "Male", Value = "Male", Selected = Model.Gender == "Male" },
    new SelectListItem{Text = "Female", Value = "Female", Selected = Model.Gender == "Female" }
}, "Select Gender", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

[SelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist?view=aspnetcore-2.1) also provides some constructors to automate this.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
  model => model.Gender, 
  new SelectList(new [] { "Male", "Female" }, Model.Gender), 
  "Select Gender", 
  new { @class = "form-control" })
```